# Disable Upload Button in AjaxFileUplaod in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am working with AjaxFileUpload control. I want to disable Upload button when file is uploaded. Again i am selecting file or drag drop file to Dropzone then display Upload button. Please tell me the solution to resolve this problem.

Comment: Why don't you want to disable it when it's clicked?

Comment: Can we have some code to refer ??

Comment: <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
          
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
                    OnUploadComplete="UploadComplete" 
                    ThrobberID="loader"/>
 
<asp:Image ID="loader" runat="server" 
           ImageUrl ="~/loading.gif" Style="display:None"/>

Comment: protected void UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)

    {

        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + e.FileName;

        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(path);

    }

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a HiddenField variable.One the file is uploaded set the value to true.And in Aspx page have a simple 
`setInterval(function () {
            var IsExpand = $('#hdnIsUploaded').val() == "1" ? true : false;
            $("input[type=file]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }, 10000);`

or
The second one you can call from c#,which is more efficient. In the disable JavaScript function 
simple  disable the control.
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Disable", "Disable();", true);`